# How to deploy persistence.xml in a web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I have a web project created with 'Dynamic Web Project'. I don't use Ant neither Maven in this project and I want to deploy the persistence.xml file to the directory WEB-INF/classes/META-INF (that is the standard place where persistence.xml should reside according to the Java EE 7 standard in a war archive), but I don't see any way to configure this in Eclipse. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Marcos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify you have to add additional path (WEB-INF/classes/META-INF - I suppose that WEB-INF is already there). After that you have to create persistence.xml and add this folder to build path (Im not pretty sure if this is a necessary condition).

Comment: My friend, I made a quick test and it seems that it worked. The addition of the folder to the build path was not needed (indeed it wasn't even allowed by Eclipse). Any issues I find I will report back. Thank you very much.